# Unable to write Antlr3 rule for situation

Tags: java, antlr3

I have a special case where I am not able to write Antlr3 parser rule for that.

I have 5 parser rules, let say: a,b,c,d and e.

**Conditions:**

1. They can be in any order.
2. Every rule is optional.
3. Each rule can only be once in syntax.
4. In syntax there would either be 'a' or 'b'. Both can not be in syntax.

Possible cases:

- a c d e
- c d e b
- d e c a
- d c a
  .........
    etc

Is Antlr provide any easy way to implement this? It is possible by implementing rule for each combination of rule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it wants others to write his code.

Comment: @Mark Do you have any answer to the question? I doubt you have any idea about Antlr.

Comment: I vote against closing this question. It's not well asked and could use some improvements, especially what the OP tried himself, but it's a totally valid and interesting question.

Comment: @Mark I disagree: it's not a trivial thing to do with Antlr and I can't see an answer to it elsewhere on SO.

Answer (score 3):

A possible way to do this would be with context-dependent predicates. How you would implement would be language dependent but it might look something like:

```
statement : element*;

element : {!seen(a) && !seen(b)}? a {add(a);}
    | {!seen(a) && !seen(b)}? b {add(b);}
    | {!seen(c) c {add(c);}
    ....
```

Essentially this stops the parser considering an option after it's been seen once.

Here is a very simple example using Java:

```
@parser::header {
    import java.util.EnumSet;
    import java.util.List;
}
@parser::members {
    public enum Val {A, B, C, D, E};
    public EnumSet<Val> result = EnumSet.noneOf(Val.class); 
}

statement : (a|b|c|d|e)+ EOF;

a : {!result.contains(Val.A) && !result.contains(Val.B)}? 'a' {result.add(Val.A);};
b : {!result.contains(Val.A) && !result.contains(Val.B)}? 'b' {result.add(Val.B);};
c : {!result.contains(Val.C)}? 'c' {result.add(Val.C);};
d : {!result.contains(Val.D)}? 'd' {result.add(Val.D);};
e : {!result.contains(Val.E)}? 'e' {result.add(Val.E);};
```

Comment: Is it possible to use predicates with parser rules?  Here a, b, c, d and e are parser rules.

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari Just store them as strings, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari I wasn't proposing exactly this code: how exactly the predicates work depend on your target code. I'd probably make it an enum and `EnumSet` myself. I can post that example if you want.

Comment: @sprinter Yes that would be helpful.

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari I've added a working sample grammar using an `enum` to store seen values. I made the members public only for my own testing: in a real case these would be private and you'd use normal grammar values to get the result.

Answer (score 3):

ANTLR4 doesn't allow to implement all those conditions you specified. Especially the condition that rules may appear in any order but only once is something that is barely supported by any parser.

However, you can use a two step approach. First, allow all rules to appear in any order. Done usually like this:

```
main: sub*;
sub: a | b | c;
```

After parsing you can do another step (usually you will have a semantic step anyway, which would qualify here too) and check the occurences in the generated parse tree. You can then throw a detailed error message telling the user what is not allowed (which is tricky, if not impossible, if you try to do that in parser rules). The approach laid out by @sprinter is ok too, but it will not give you any meaningful error message, but just tell you that rule `element` had no viable alt (which can have many reasons, not only duplicate rules).

And with that second step you can easily apply any additional condition (specific orders, rules that must not go together etc., without having to change your grammar), which you cannot do in the parsing step (since you cannot lookahead rules).

Comment: That's what I would do. It's worth mentioning though that you can only do this if you don't need to enforce the rule at parse-time (i.e. if this doesn't lead to ambiguity) - it's not likely to happen, but not impossible.

Comment: Very good point you make about my approach not allowing useful error messages to be generated. I guess how important that is depends on the usage.